# How to create and connect to a test database with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, integration-testing, entity-framework-migrations

I have a Web API project accessing a database file in its App_Data folder. The database is created using EF Migrations.

I have some integration tests to confirm data structures and queries. They just create a Web API controller and use it to perform queries. My Test Project has an App.config file, which currently has an **absolute path** to the *.mdf database file (in the web api project).

This is a problem because a) I am doing my tests on the application database, and b) I have an absolute path in my App.config file.

I would like to create a test database in the test project.

Is there some way I can get Migrations to create another database (with a different Seed method) in the Test Project?

In the Web Api project's Web.config connection string we use `|DataDirectory|` to specify the location of the database. Is there an equivalent in a test project's App.config?

Failing all that, is there some way I can point the test project's connection string to the application db without using an absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to have a static `DbManager` class that does a `Setup()`, which I will run from the `[ClassInitialize]` method of the database testing classes. `Setup()`will:

1. Change the connection string according to the current `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` (so no longer an absolute path in App.config).
2. Use other AppSettings from App.config to determine which database to use, which test data set to use, and whether or not to drop and recreate the database.

Some code:

```
public static class DbManager
{
    private static string ErrorMsg { get; set; }
    private static ApplicationDbContext _db;
    private static readonly Random Rdm = new Random();

    public static void SetupDb()
    {
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        bool refreshDb = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RefreshDbInTestClassInitialization"]);
        string dataSet = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataSetToAddForEachTestClass"];
        string dbName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testDatabaseName"];

        var connectionStr = config.ConnectionStrings
            .ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString
            .Replace("{dbPath}", Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, (dbName + ".mdf")))
            .Replace("{dbName}", dbName);

        config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString = connectionStr;
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");

        if (refreshDb)
        {
            Database.Delete(connectionStr);
            AddDataSet(dataSet, true);
        }
    }

    // AddDataSet() creates a DbContext object and generates test data.

}
```

So the connection string in App.config looks like this:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename={dbPath};Initial Catalog={dbName};Integrated Security=True"
```

Then App.config AppSettings section has these extra key value pairs:

```
<add key ="RefreshDbInTestClassInitialization" value ="true"/>
<add key="DataSetToAddForEachTestClass" value="Large"/>  <!--Possible values: Large, Small-->
<add key="testDatabaseName" value="testDb"/>
```